# Working with PiCAN + raspberry pi 3 running windows IoT Core

Tags: driver, universal, raspberry-pi3, can-bus, windows-iot-core-10

I want to connect the PiCAN with my raspberry pi3 running windows IoT Core. I think I need a universal driver for the mcp2515 to work with the windows in Pi. I already tried using the instructions given in  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/driverdeployment to deploy the driver given in https://github.com/AustinWise/Mcp2515Can . But I got stuck in the instructions. I hope someone has already done this and maybe can help me with it? Did anyone successfully use this CAN board with Raspberry Pi (windows iot core)?
Thank you :)

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Is a driver required in the first place? I tried enabling the SPI pin of the raspberry pi and tried to read something or send something to the PiCan - CAN Bus . For testing pupose, I used PeakCAN USB cable to generate CAN messages to be sent to the PiCAN2 board via a DB9 cable. But, even after enabling the SPI, I couldn't receive anything on the Raspberry Pi. I feel like I am missing something. I haven't used any driver. I have just connected the PiCAN2 board to Raspberry Pi. Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi @njoshy did you manage to get you win iot core to communicate with the Pican2 ?
Just got a board and seeing if I can get one to work

Comment: @TrueSolutions Sorry No. I used a PEAK CAN interface system instead. Troubleshooting the mcp driver+ Raspberry Pi connection was quite time consuming so I did not pursue it after a while.

Comment: @njoshy is their a libary/nuget then that can use in a win IOT project ?

Comment: @TrueSolutions I did not understand your question. PEAK CAN has a straightforward interface that is easy to use. It is almost like plug and play. There was a git for the MCP driver(it was still in development that time) but i don't have it with me now. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

> Is a driver required in the first place?

Short answer is No.

Although a device driver is preferred, such work is not officially or community done yet.

The benefit you get from developing a device driver might include:

1. Native OS support for PiCAN board.
2. Create your [create the custom IoT image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/iot/iot-core-manufacturing-guide), and deploy it to Microsoft store.
3. Possible performance improvements
4. others…

However, in order to [develop an device driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/getting-started-with-universal-drivers), you need to follow the WDK framework. If you are comfortable with picking up new stuff, go ahead and try it out. You might need to refer to the [linux source driver code](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/24e62728b3fc4f118c8ae17b374bce189bb188fc/drivers/net/can/spi/mcp251x.c) for WDK driver developing.

If your purpose is to get the board working, you don’t need to get yourself into all these troubles.

In fact, you only need to get the SPI controller and GPIO controller, open the SPI device and initialize GPIO interrupt pin like [Mcp2515Can](https://github.com/AustinWise/Mcp2515Can/tree/master/CanTestApp) does.

> But, even after enabling the SPI, I couldn't receive anything on the
>   Raspberry Pi.

First, you can use [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and turn on the CAN driver support to verify that you got all the wirings right. Here is the [user guide](http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/images/raspberrypi/pi_2/PICAN2UGB.pdf) you can reference.

If you can rule out the possibility of hardware failures, step into your C# code to troubleshoot the software.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite informaitve. I will try checking for any hardware failures with Raspbian. I can rule that part out then. I will get back to you once I do this. Thank you again!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to simulate CAN messages from PC to Pican2 board connected to Raspberry Pi (PC - USB - VN1610 - PiCAN2 - raspberry Pi) using vector device VN1610 http://vector.com/vi_vn1600_en.html ? Maybe any of the applications like CANalyzer/CANape/CANoe ? Any idea?

Comment: Would be keen on update if you got this to work on WinIot